# Why ckeditor is invisible on browser?

Tags: jquery, razor, ckeditor

I have loaded ckeditor this way in in my Create.html (One of MVC files of VS 2017).

// for testing I have used inline scripting

```
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DetailDescription, new {@id = "_DetailDescription", @rows="20",@cols="10"})
                <script> // destroy ckeditor instaces
                    if (CKEDITOR.instances['_DetailDescription']) {
                        CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['_DetailDescription']);
                    };
                    //initialize CKEditor by givin id of textarea
                    CKEDITOR.replace('_DetailDescription');
                    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
                        ignoreEmptyParagraph = true;
                    };
                </script>
                @*<textarea rows="10" id="DetailDescription"></textarea>*@   
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DetailDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                   
            </div>
```

when I run the project I can see the instance of ckeditor is loaded in both browser firefox and chrome which I can see in inspection mode as follows

```
                <textarea cols="10" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Description field is required." id="_DetailDescription" name="DetailDescription" rows="20" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea><span id="cke__DetailDescription" class="cke_skin_kama cke_1 cke_editor__DetailDescription" dir="ltr" title=" " role="application" aria-labelledby="cke__DetailDescription_arialbl" lang="en"><span id="cke__DetailDescription_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Rich Text Editor</span><span class="cke_browser_gecko" role="presentation"><span class="cke_wrapper cke_ltr" role="presentation"><table class="cke_editor" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr role="presentation" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><td id="cke_top__DetailDescription" class="cke_top" role="presentation"><div class="cke_toolbox" role="group" aria-labelledby="cke_6" onmousedown="return false;"><span id="cke_6" class="cke_voice_label">Editor toolbars</span><span id="cke_7" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_7_label" role="toolbar"><span id="cke_7_label" class="cke_voice_label">Document</span><span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span><span class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation"><span class="cke_button"><a id="cke_8" class="cke_off cke_button_source" title="Source" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_8_label" onblur="this.style.cssText = this.style.cssText;" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(4, event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(5, event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(6, this); return false;">
```

......................

but the ckeditor is white blank, none of the toolbar or border is visible at all.

Does anyone have idea or something I did wrong with css???

Thank you.

Comment: Open your browser dev-tools (F12 in Chrome or Firefox) and check if you are getting any JavaScript or HTTP errors in Network and Console tab. In Network tab you may get e.g. 404 because path to css file is invalid or 403 because css file is in not accessible location. In Console tab you may get JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yea I had a look  dev-tools in both Firefox and Chrome only thing I can see is 404 for css file : bootstrap.css.map is missing otherwise there is no other issues noted.

Comment: I don't recall any such file in CKEditor and I really don't know why you are getting the result you are getting. Try installing CKEditor as standalone application on your server. If it works you will know there is something in your app that blocks editor CSS. If it doesn't you will know that your editor instance is invalid (perhaps you modified it and removed some CSS from it). in such a case please download one of default packages and retry.